# Conditional summing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble getting a query to work.  What I'm trying to do is sum a counter by user id but with conditions.

Currently my query gives the following output.

```
User ID  EndDate    Date       Index
 123      5/1/12   1/1/12       -1
 123      5/1/12   1/25/12       1
 123      5/1/12   2/13/12      -1
 456      4/1/12   1/18/12      -1
 456      4/1/12   2/15/12      -1
 456      4/1/12   2/18/12       1
```

What I want to do with this list is sum the Index by User Id but with a catch.  The Index must be summed in date order, also the min value of the index is -1 and max is 1, so the values can be -1, 0, 1 only.  So with user 123, the process would be -1 then you add 1 then you add -1 for a final sum of -1.  But for user 456 you start with -1 then you have -1 again but the sum must remain -1 then you have 1, so the final sum is 0.    Below is what I'm been trying to do but I can't figure it out.  I would really appreciate some help.

```
DECLARE @Period char(6)
DECLARE @StatusCount int
    SET @Period = '201201'
    SET @StatusCount = 0

SELECT     Q1.UserID, Q1.End_Date,
            Sum(Case 
                When Index = -1 Then Case When @IndexCount >=0 Then @IndexCount - 1 Else @IndexCount + 0 End
                When Index = 1 Then Case When @IndexCount <=0 Then @IndexCount + 1 Else @IndexCount + 0 End
            END) as FinalIndex

FROM 
(
    (SELECT    UserID,  End_Date, Enter_Dt, 1 as Index
    FROM        UserTable 
    WHERE       (Code in ('A', 'B') and PRD = @Period)
    GROUP BY    UserID,  End_Date, Enter_Dt)

         UNION

    (SELECT     UserID,  End_Date, Enter_Dt, -1 as Index
    FROM         UserTable 
    WHERE     (Code in ('C', 'D') and PRD = @Period)
    GROUP BY    UserID,  End_Date, Enter_Dt)
) as Q1

GROUP BY Q1.UserID, Q1.End_Date
ORDER BY Q1.UserID ASC, Q1.End_Date ASC
```

I think my main problem is I can't figure out how to accumulate the Index properly.  I can't get IndexCount to remember the the previous value and then start again from 0 with the next User ID

The result I get with this query is

```
User ID    EndDate       Index
 123       5/01/12       -1
 456       4/01/12       -1
```

Which is just summing the Index

Comment: which SQL... SQL Server, MySQL?  I can do it relatively easy with MySQL in a single SQL-Select call, but how/where is your 0 condition... or is that just a "net result" of the computation.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. You would get a 0 if there were 2 entries for a user 1 and -1.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a running sum on Index ordered by date and partitioned on userid?

Comment: Yes, but the sum is bounded on the lower end by -1 and on the upper end by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll illustrate a running total by userID solution here, leaving out the other details of your query for clarity. Basically, add a IndexRT column populate it with a running total that resets for each new userID.

**EDIT**: constrain running total to -1,0,1

```
create table #temp(userID int, [Index] int, IndexRT int) 
insert into #temp (userID,[Index]) values (123,-1) , (123,1) , (123,-1) , (456,-1) , (456,-1) , (456,1)  
declare @rt int; set @rt=0;

with a as (
    select select TOP 100 percent *
    ,r=ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by userID order by userID) 
    from #temp order by userID,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by userID order by userID) 
) 
update a set @rt = [IndexRT] = case when case when r=1 then [Index] else @rt + [Index] end between -1 and 1
then case when r=1 then [Index] else @rt + [Index] end
else @rt
end

select * from #temp;
go 
drop table #temp;
```

Result:

```
userID      Index       IndexRT
----------- ----------- -----------
123         -1          -1
123         1           0
123         -1          -1
456         -1          -1
456         -1          -1
456         1           0
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but your query doesn't constraint the IndexRT result to -1.

Comment: Use `TOP 100 PERCENT` instead if `TOP (2147483647)`, more elegant and correct, the table might have more records than the max value of signed 32 bit integer.

Comment: Surely you must `PARTITION BY UserID *ORDER BY [Date]*`, otherwise the rows might come back numbered in the wrong order rather than by [Date] as the OP desires, no?

Comment: The exact details of sorting are trivial and omitted from this example for brevity. That is why dates are omitted from #temp.

Comment: The exact details of sorting are what give users 123 and 456 different "sums" despite identical groups of "addends". :)

Comment: I would suggest re-reading the problem statement, esp. this part: _I think my main problem is I can't figure out how to accumulate the Index properly. I can't get IndexCount to remember the the previous value and then start again from 0 with the next User ID_ That's the issue I'm addressing here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to define a cycling sequence:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html

This will create the effect you've described in your problem, cycling -1,0,1 as rows iterate. You can achieve this in a select or upon inserting the record in your table.

Comment: After reading the link you provided as well as other sources, I don't believe a cycling sequence will work, unless I'm missing something.  From what I understand, you can only increment in one direction.  Also when you reach the max or min value, you either cycle back to your start value, which I don't want or you get an error, not desirable either.

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of what you think the results should look like in the format you used above for your current results.

Answer (score 0):

This uses cursors, and seemed to work in SQL 2005 (I would advise checking your results thoroughly in case I missed something obvious here).

As a disclaimer, most database experts will tell you that cursors are horrible, inefficient, and should never be used. And yes-- you should use straight SELECT statements when possible. However: (1) I don't know that there is a straightforward SELECT statement for this type of accumulation, and (2) this will be a much more readable solution for anyone who has to maintain your code. If your data set is not unreasonably large (and you don't expect it to grow too much), cursors should be OK.

Note that I have substituted "Table3" for your entire FROM statement; I imported your sample table to create this example. The key element to note here is that I am sorting it first by User ID, then by Date in the `DECLARE csrOrdered CURSOR` statement. So you should just need to substitute your own sorted SQL statement in the cursor definition.

```
CREATE TABLE #sumResult (
    [User ID] int,
    [Sum Result] int
)

DECLARE csrOrdered CURSOR FOR
SELECT [User Id], [Index] FROM Table3 -- <- your table name goes here!
ORDER BY [User ID], Date, EndDate

DECLARE @uid int
DECLARE @index int
DECLARE @lastUid int
DECLARE @curSum int

SET @uid=0
SET @index=0
SET @lastUid=0
SET @curSum=0

OPEN csrOrdered

FETCH NEXT FROM csrOrdered
INTO @uid, @index

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    --Are we working on a new User ID? Then reset the sum and insert the last group into the table.
    IF @uid<>@lastUid BEGIN
        --Don't do an insert if we just got into the loop
         IF @lastUid <> 0 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #sumResult ([User ID], [Sum Result]) VALUES (@lastUid, @curSum)
         END
        SET @curSum=0
        SET @lastUid=@uid
    END

    SET @curSum = @curSum + @index
    IF @curSum < -1 SET @curSum=-1
    IF @curSum > 1 SET @curSum=1

    FETCH NEXT FROM csrOrdered
    INTO @uid, @index
END

IF @lastUid <> 0 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #sumResult ([User ID], [Sum Result]) VALUES (@lastUid, @curSum)
END

CLOSE csrOrdered
DEALLOCATE csrOrdered

SELECT * FROM #sumResult

DROP TABLE #sumResult
```